# network_mode: service:<serviceName> not working correctly

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to configure a docker-compose stack with a container that connects to a VPN, and another container that exposes an HTTP service which is reachable only through that VPN connection.
I searched online and found that `network_mode: service:<serviceName>` setting in docker-compose.yml should do the trick, but it is not working in my environment.

If I start the two containers separately with `docker run` and `--network=container:<containerName>` setting, everything works and I can correctly connect to the remote HTTP service with `curl localhost:8080`

Here is the working configuration with two separate commands:

```
docker run --rm --name vpn --privileged --hostname vpn --publish 127.0.0.1:8080:80 --device /dev/net/tun --cap-add NET_ADMIN registry.internal.com/vpnclient

docker run --rm --name proxy --network=container:vpn registry.internal.com/proxy
```

And here is docker-compose.yml that is not working:

```
version: '3'

services:
  vpn:
    container_name: vpn
    image:  registry.internal.com/vpnclient
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    devices:
      - /dev/net/tun
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
    restart: unless-stopped


  proxy:
    container_name: proxy
    image: registry.internal.com/proxy
    depends_on:
      - vpn
    network_mode: service:vpn
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Comment: Also posted on https://forums.docker.com/t/network-mode-service-servicename-not-working/121242

Answer (score 1):

In the `docker run` version you use `--hostname vpn` and that is lacking in the `docker compose` version.

Adding a `hostname: vpn` beneath the `container_name: vpn` in the `docker-compose.yml` should fix the problem.

*Explanation:*

*Because not setting this parameter modifies the `/etc/hosts` file and the response of the `hostname` command, its absence can cause the problem if this 'hostname' is somehow required in the 'proxy' container which seems to be the case here.*

The `container_name: vpn` parameter only fixes the container name and should be only meaningful to *docker* commands. It matches the `--name vpn` option of the `docker run` command.

The last `vpn` name involved here is the one that comes from the `services:` section of the docker-compose.yml file. This will allow containers to join using their service name through the networking features provided by docker.

(**update:** I should add that I'm not saying here that making what's running in the container depend on this "hostname" is good practice. In fact, I even *have the feeling* it can be a problem in some environments, but *I could be wrong too*.)

Comment: Adding hostname:vpn fixes it. This answer is still a little convoluted and should be made more clear, because it does answer the question.